# STM32 cant adjust sample frequency with adc dma

Tags: c, timer, stm32, adc

I am using stm32wl55jc1. I want to use accelerometer at 50khz and microphone at 2khz (2048). I am trying to make fft. With pooling adc method, I can do that easily.

```
for(int i=0;i<128;i++)
{
microSecond=micros();
HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc,1);
readValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
data[i] = readValue;
delay_us(500+microSecond);
}
FFT(data,128,2000);
```

This code gives me the right frequency of tone.

I shouldn't blok the cpu so I need to use dma. I am trying to use timer 2 for adc dma. But I couldn't manage it. Even if I change the timer2 preseceler or counter period, sampling frequency is not changing. This codes gives me wrong frequency of tone.

```
uint32_t ADC_VAL[adc_bufflength];
uint32_t fft_in[128];
char is_data_ready_for_fft = 0;
uint32_t timer_value=0;
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc,(uint32_t *)ADC_VAL,adc_bufflength);
while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      htim1.Instance -> CNT=0;

      if(is_data_ready_for_fft==1)
      {
          /*for (size_t i=0; i<adc_bufflength;i++)
          {
          fft_in[i] = ADC_VAL[i];
          }*/
          FFT(ADC_VAL,128,2048);
          is_data_ready_for_fft=0;
          timer_value = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim1);
      }

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
  is_data_ready_for_fft = 1;
}
```

Even if I change timer 2 preseceler or counter period, timer_value doesn't change. Here is my adc and timer2 setup code :

```
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc.Instance = ADC;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIG_T2_TRGO;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  hadc.Init.SamplingTimeCommon1 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_79CYCLES_5;
  hadc.Init.SamplingTimeCommon2 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  hadc.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.TriggerFrequencyMode = ADC_TRIGGER_FREQ_HIGH;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_Init 2 */

}

static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 120000;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */

}

static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how the DMA is configured?